# serve static file with herokku, django and wsgi

Tags: django, heroku, wsgi

I was working to deploy a website to heroku. The site seems to recognize my static files if I run with django's builtin server namely "**runserver**". However if I run with  **gunicorn** The static files cannot be recognized. I was wondering if there's any special setting I need to tweak to magically make the recognition happen. Can anyone enlighten me how these two commands differ specifically or does it have anything to do with wsgi staff?

**Thanks**!!!

This is how I do with **runserver** in **Procfile**, which is quite neat.

> web:python manage.py runserver

[image]
And here's what I do with **gunicorn** in **Procfile**, which is a mess

> web: gunicorn some.dotted.path.to.mywsgi:application

[image]

**UPDATE**

Luckily I worked around this problem by including the following line to my urls.py. Though I know it's not a perfect solution because in real word, you need to shutdown DEBUG. but as for now in development. it's working well. Can anyone explain what this line magically do?

```
if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
                                      url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
                             )
```

Comment: The django development server ('runserver') is NOT intended for use in production (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port).

Comment: yeap I know. That's why I am  annoyed. I have to use gunicorn xxx.wsgi but it didn't work right

Answer (score 1):

Serving static files on Heroku with Django is a bit tricky. Assuming you're using the 'staticfiles' app, you have to run 'collectstatic' to collect your static files after deploying. The problem with Heroku is that running 'collectstatic' in the shell will actually run in a new dyno, which disappears as soon as it's finished.

One potential solution is outlined [here](http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku):

Basically, the idea is to combine a few commands in your Procfile so that 'collectstatic' is run during the dyno spinup process:

```
web: python my_django_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; bin/gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT my_django_app/settings.py
```

You also have to add the 'static' views to your `urls.py` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user, but duplicate for `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`). It's worth noting that the Django docs recommend against using this in production.

This solution isn't ideal though, since you are still using your gunicorn process to serve static files. IMHO the best approach to dealing with static files on Heroku is to host them on something like S3.

Comment: Actually, according to Heroku, they now automatically attempt to run collectstatic when spinning up a dyno (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets). You'd still need to set up your urls. The development server adds static urls automatically.